# Python: how to sort an array with integers and letters?

Tags: python, arrays

When I have a `list` of integers and letters,
I want to sort these elements by some order.
For example,

```
ex_array = [1, 3, 2', 2, 1', 3', 3]
```

should be sorted to

```
sorted(ex_array) = [1', 1, 2', 2, 3', 3, 3]
```

In this case the order of letters is given by

```
1' < 1 < 2' < 2 < 3' < 3.
```

I can make a code when consisting of only integers.
But I don't know how to compare the symbols with primed with unprimed.

Could you tell me what to do in Python?

Comment: What is `1'`? Do you mean `"1'"` or `"1"`?

Comment: It just a symbol. But I need to distinguish them.

Comment: You should distinguish by quotes then. `"1"` or `'1'` is string, `1` is int and `1'` is syntax error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort by the integer value of each element, as well as whether that element is an integer:

```
>>> a = [1, 3, '2', 2, '1', '3', 3, '10', 10, 'potato', "1'", lambda: None, '-3', -3, -4]
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda x: (int(''.join(v for i,v in enumerate(str(x)) if v.isdigit() or (i==0 and v=='-')) or 0), isinstance(x, int)))
[-4, '-3', -3, 'potato', '1', "1'", 1, '2', 2, '3', 3, 3, '10', 10, <function <lambda> at 0x000000DAD51DB9D8>]
```

If two elements have the same integer value, the string will be placed before the integer.

Comment: @schwobaseggl - You're absolutely right. Changed from `str` to `int`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl - `1'` is a syntax error, so I assume they mean a string. You could do `int(x.strip("'"))` if the elements were actually strings like `"1'"` though.

Comment: @schwobaseggl - Well, the new edit makes it a lot more robust. It even handles arbitrary values like `'potato'`.

Comment: of course `str.isdigit()` won't work with negative values, but that's pretty hard to achieve.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - With the edit, it handles that as well.

Comment: I guess it could still be made to fail if you wanted to sort an object that had a `__str__` of `raise` (or `pass`, or anything that causes an error when called), but that would be pretty inconvenient.

Comment: Hehe. Can it handle a pandas, bs4 and other libraries object in PyPI? Not good enough then :D

Comment: @MYGz - As long as those objects have a `__str__` that doesn't raise an exception when called, it'll sort those elements in some way instead of crashing, but, since there's an infinite variety of potential definitions of `__str__`, the behavior for such objects is undefined.